# trying to understand .loc in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'b':['g1','g1','g1','g1','g2','g2','g2','g2'],'c':['v1','v2','v1','v2','v1','v2','v1','v2']})
df.set_index(['b','c'], inplace=True)

>> df
       a
b  c    
g1 v1  1
   v2  2
   v1  3
   v2  4
g2 v1  5
   v2  6
   v1  7
   v2  8
```

why does `df.loc['g1','v1']` return,

```
       a  
b  c    
g1 v1  1
   v1  3
```

shouldn't the second element of `.loc[row,col]` be a column label? Because in my example 'v1' is not a column label.

And why doesn't `df.loc[:,'v1']` then return,

```
       a  
b  c    
g1 v1  1
   v1  3
g2 v1  5
   v1  7
```

how can I get the output above?

Comment: This is multiple index , so it is different https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And for multiple index , you can using query

```
df.query("c=='v1'")
Out[255]: 
       a
b  c    
g1 v1  1
   v1  3
g2 v1  5
   v1  7
```

Or `IndexSlice`

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, 'v1'],:]
Out[257]: 
       a
b  c    
g1 v1  1
   v1  3
g2 v1  5
   v1  7
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example the dataframe has multiindex (i.e. indexed over several columns). So, row keys are iterables instead of a single value. So, in the `df.loc['g1','v1']` example pandas interprets `('g1','v1')` as a row index instead of firsrt column of multiindex and a column.

If you want to index only on the first column of the index, use an iterable type (possible incomplete) as a row index:

```
df.loc[['g1'],'a']
```